# How to override the setter?

Tags: c++

I have an private property in my class and I want to add some code on its setter, how can I accomplish that?

I might do that using method but I don't want to just to avoid using property.

```
private:
    float damage;
```

Comment: Can you phrase your question a bit better? It's a little unclear of what exactly you want.

Comment: C++ doesn't have "properties" like C# does. You would use a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your plain old data type with a class type to do what you want:

```
class Damage
{
public:
    Damage& operator=(float x) { value = x; /* add code here*/ }
    operator float() const { return value; }

private:
    float value;
};
```

Then just replace your `float` with `Damage` and you can make it behave how you want.

Comment: I think this class has little advantage over using a plain `float`. If the goal is to enhance type safety, one should replace the conversion operator with an explicit member function and consider making the constructor `explicit`, too.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: the advantage is that it allows inserting code (behavior) in the assignment (setter).  It's not about type safety, it's about fulfilling the OP's requirement.  In any case, yes, the class I wrote is incomplete and might be improved in various ways depending on details from the OP's code that aren't known here.